# XHR onreadystatechange never fires

Tags: javascript, ajax, require, amd

I have an AMD module that does basic Ajax posting. It is working, it will Post to my server api, however the onreadystatechange event just will not fire. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?...

```
define(['constants'], function (cons) {
    'use strict';

    function _getHTTPObject () {
        var http = false;
        // Use IE's ActiveX items to load the file.
        if (typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined') {
            try {http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
            catch (e) {
                try {http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
                catch (E) {http = false;}
            }
        // If ActiveX is not available, use the XMLHttpRequest of Firefox/Mozilla etc. to load the document.
        } else if (XMLHttpRequest) {
            try {http = new XMLHttpRequest();}
            catch (e) {http = false;}
        }
        return http;
    }

    function _send (url, params, cbSuccess, cbError) {
        var http = _getHTTPObject();
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        // Send the proper header infomation along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.onreadystatechange = function (cbSuccess, cbError) { 
            if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                if (console) { console.log('xhrPost response:', http.responseText); }
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }

    return {
        send: _send
    };

});
```

Comment: Note: You simply do not need `_getHTTPObject` unless you're supporting truly amazingly obsolete browsers like IE6.

Comment: It's not the problem, but it's the *next* problem: You don't want to declare `cbSuccess` and `cbError` in your `onreadystatechange` handler's signature.

Comment: I thought about that. However, I want to add a way for this to return the success or error. So you _do not_ think that function signature is causing the event to fail?

Comment: You want them on `_send`. You don't want them on the `onreadystatechange` handler. No, I don't think it's the problem. (I don't think the problem's in the quoted code at all, in fact, unless it's throwing an error out of `_getHTTPObject` that you haven't noticed.)

Comment: What makes you think onreadystate change never fires? It doesn't do anything unless it gets to status 4 with a 200 OK response.

Comment: E.g., it may well be that the thing you're calling is failing with a 404 or 500.

Comment: I've moved the console.log out of the if block and set it show readyState. It fires once with readyState = 1, which is the connection success, but you never see the subsequent readyState = 4 that you should. There is no 404 or 500, the api is getting called because I see the messages in the server log and the new records in the database.

Comment: Just had and idea: The server api is returning straight JSON. I bet my header/content type is wrong...

Comment: That didn't work. The header contenttype is for what you're sending, not receiving. Is it because it's an AMD module?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... So after a lot of fiddling with the javascript, I finally saw the issue. My server api post route I was testing with, was not returning a response on success, just on error, so it took forever to see that.

So the code above is fine :-/

Here is the sever Node route code if anyone is interested. I had to add the `return res.json(...` line after the player save success to get the correct readyState to fire...

```
app.post('/api/player/create', function (req, res) {
    var player = new Player({
            'firstName': req.body.firstName,
            'lastName': req.body.lastName,
            'handle': req.body.handle,
            'email': req.body.email
        });
    player.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            log.logOK('New player joined! (%0)', req.body.handle);
            return res.json({ 'error': '' }); // <== This was missing
        } else {
            log.logER('Create new player failed, error (%0): %1', req.player.handle, err);
            return res.json({ 'error': err });
        }
    });
});
```